# Problem with integer field format in Drupal 7

Tags: entities

I just created an integer field for one of my content types. I'm using it to display a value for a year. However, when it is displayed, it is putting in a space between the 1000s column and the 100s column; so, for example, "1991" is displayed as "1 991".

I'm guessing this is something to do with the formatting of the field. Can anyone tell me how I can correct this or change the formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the "Manage display" tab and edit "Thousand marker".

Comment: Thank you kalabro, I didn't realise it was so obvious! I was busy look for a complicated solution! :)